# FBFriendPickerViewController (FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController) has no navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios8

In `iOS 8` `FBFriendPickerViewController` is shown without navigation bar (in `iOS 7` everything was perfect).
I use `Facebook-iOS-SDK` v3.9.0, but I checked with latest SDK and there is same behaviour also (I run sample project called `Scrumptious`).

Code:

```
- (void)pickFacebookFriends{
    FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    ABPersonSortOrdering sortOrdering = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
    ABPersonCompositeNameFormat nameFormat = ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormatForRecord(NULL);

    friendPicker.sortOrdering = (sortOrdering == kABPersonSortByFirstName) ? FBFriendSortByFirstName : FBFriendSortByLastName;
    friendPicker.displayOrdering = (nameFormat == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst) ? FBFriendDisplayByFirstName : FBFriendDisplayByLastName;
    friendPicker.fieldsForRequest = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"picture", nil];
    [friendPicker loadData];
    [friendPicker presentModallyFromViewController:self
                                          animated:YES
                                           handler:^(FBViewController *sender, BOOL donePressed) {
                                               if (donePressed) {
                                                   if (friendPicker.selection.count > 0) {

                                                       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }
                                               }}];
    return;

    [self presentViewController:friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is screenshot:
 [image]

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same situation. I didn't find any useful answer, can you solved this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you nav.bar doesn't hide and do push.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

_taggableFriendPickerViewController = [FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController new];
[_taggableFriendPickerViewController loadData];
_taggableFriendPickerViewController.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_taggableFriendPickerViewController animated:YES];

#pragma mark - FBViewControllerDelegate

///When you press on done button will call this method.
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(FBViewController *)sender
{
 _arrayWithUsers = ((FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController *)sender).selection;
}
```

Comment: In this case I don't know delegate method, which will be fired when "Done" button clicked.

Comment: Delegate for FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController it's FBViewControllerDelegate. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks Iraklii! Just the same code I was looking for, for getting the FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to conform to `<FBViewControllerDelegate>`, then:

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
    friendPicker.delegate = self;
    ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    ABPersonSortOrdering sortOrdering = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
    ABPersonCompositeNameFormat nameFormat = ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormatForRecord(NULL);

    friendPicker.sortOrdering = (sortOrdering == kABPersonSortByFirstName) ? FBFriendSortByFirstName : FBFriendSortByLastName;
    friendPicker.displayOrdering = (nameFormat == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst) ? FBFriendDisplayByFirstName : FBFriendDisplayByLastName;
    friendPicker.fieldsForRequest = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"picture", nil];
    [friendPicker loadData];

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:friendPicker];
[self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = sender;
    NSLog(friendPicker.selection.description);
}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: @Schmidt Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, the navbar is missing. I can't attach a picture, please see this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4v4hmo2i2aujyp0/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-24%20at%2014.37.31.png?dl=0)

Comment: @szokolov try to push friendPicker instead

Comment: @Schmidt Thanks, this is half the battle. The "Done" button is present, but "Cancel" button is missing yet. See this [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiyusce5ce7g6ta/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-24%20at%2015.32.47.png?dl=0).